# IEnumerator reference in a List returns NULL/Can't be used as coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a list of SubMenuItems and each item in the list has a name, description, and a IEnumerator reference. When trying to use StartCoroutine with any selected list items IEnumerator reference it gives a routine is null. I understand that means it cannot find it/appear it doesn't exist but I can perfectly find the name and description with no issues.

The purpose for this system is to run an ability when its selected from a menu during some turn based combat/on the players turn.

Does anyone know how I can make this work or a better method of doing this?

SubMenuItems:

```
public class SubMenuItems 
{
    public string description;
    public string itemName;
    public IEnumerator actionAbility;

    public SubMenuItems(string _itemName, string _description, IEnumerator _actionAbility) 
    {
        itemName = _itemName;
        description = _description;
        actionAbility = _actionAbility;
    }
}
```

List item example:

```
public List<SubMenuItems> tacticsList = new List<SubMenuItems>();

public void PopLists() 
{
    tacticsList.Add (new SubMenuItems("Run", "Run away", CombatAbilities.instance.Run()));
}
```

Trying to run the coroutine from another script example:

```
if (key == KeyCode.E) 
{
    StartCoroutine(CombatAbilities.instance.Run()); //Correctly runs the Coroutine            
    print(activeSubMenu.description); //Correctly shows "Run"
    print(activeSubMenu.itemName); //Correctly shows "Run Away"
    print(activeSubMenu.actionAbility); //returns null
    StartCoroutine(activeSubMenu.actionAbility); //doesn't work but should be the same as StartCoroutine(CombatAbilities.instance.Run());
}
```

Comment: There might be an issue with your Enumerator function itself, rather than the calling code. However, instead of passing down a IEnumerator, pass an action reference. It is much easier to understand, you can still call IEnumerator from the Passed Action. Would you like me to write you an example?

Comment: Could you show the code of `CombatAbilities.instance.Run` ?

Answer (score 0):

"Works on my machine" ;)

You didn't add all information about what `CombatAbilities.instance.Run` is exactly so I  just created a little test myself

```
[Serializable]
public class SubMenuItems
{
    public string description;
    public string itemName;
    public IEnumerator actionAbility;

    public SubMenuItems(string _itemName, string _description, IEnumerator _actionAbility)
    {
        itemName = _itemName;
        description = _description;
        actionAbility = _actionAbility;
    }
}

public class CombatAbilities
{
    public static CombatAbilities instance => new CombatAbilities();

    public IEnumerator Run()
    {
        Debug.Log("1");

        yield return null;
        
        Debug.Log("2");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        
        Debug.Log("3");
    }
}

public class TEST : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<SubMenuItems> tacticsList = new List<SubMenuItems>();

    [ContextMenu(nameof(PopLists))]
    public void PopLists()
    {
        tacticsList.Add(new SubMenuItems("Run", "Run away", CombatAbilities.instance.Run()));
    }

    [ContextMenu(nameof(Test))]
    public void Test()
    {
        StartCoroutine(tacticsList[0].actionAbility);
    }
}
```

And as you can see it just works as expected:

[image]

So according to my findings I'm sorry but I have to claim the issue is with you ;)

Are you sure the `actionAbility` is changed by nothing else? To be sure you could/should simply make the fields [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) so they can not be altered afterwards:

```
public class SubMenuItems
{
    public readonly string description;
    public readonly string itemName;
    public readonly IEnumerator actionAbility;

    public SubMenuItems(string _itemName, string _description, IEnumerator _actionAbility)
    {
        itemName = _itemName;
        description = _description;
        actionAbility = _actionAbility;
    }
}
```